# How to fill Vaadin Grid with Map items type

Tags: java, spring, vaadin

I want to fill my Vaadin Grid with `Map<String, Object>` items. 
Thats because I get my data from database like this(maybe it's main problem):

```
List<Map<String, Object>> result = jdbcTemplate.queryForList("select * from db", new Object[]{});
```

Now lets say that I create my test List and fill it with some maps:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> items = new ArrayList<>();
items.add(map);
items.add(map2);
```

I know how to do it with non dynamic data model, for example:

```
grid.addColumn(Person::getName).setCaption("Name");
grid.addColumn(Person::getAge).setCaption("Age");
```

But how can I create my Grid columns so it will use my keys from map?
What I have by now:

```
Grid<Map<String, Object>> grid = new Grid<>();

items.get(0).keySet().forEach(key ->
    grid.addColumn(c -> c.get(key)));

grid.setItems(items);
```

It gives me output:

> b2 / b3 / b1

And expected:

> a1 / a2 / a3
>
> b1 / b2 / b3

I have no clue how can I get to my item in every single map in list. And also why doesnt it keep an order?
Appreciate every answer!

Comment: Are you sure, that this really is a setup problem and not a problem with the items/your list itself? The wrong order (b2,b3,b1) is most likely your keySet/map not being ordered/sorted (e.g. a HashMap)

Comment: **1)** Are the keys in both maps equal? If not, then for your second list all the values for each column will be null. **2)** [Order in hash-maps is not guaranteed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), if that's what you're using. Please consider adding a [sscce](http://sscce.org) which fully illustrates what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks, it actually was items problem! And yes, order is not kept cuz of lack of sorting. What about my jdbcquery? Isn't it a bit nasty?

Comment: Your comment regarding the nastiness of your query is a totally new issue, not related to this one, so it would normally require a separate question. **However** it may also indicate that you need to go over an introduction to SQL queries, [Spring JDBC](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html), or whatever framework you use, before posting the new question. If you're already familiar with the concepts and have a precise problem, you can post a question, but asking something so generic is not really meant for SO. Let me know if i'm missing something.

Comment: Thanks for all answers @Morfic im familiar with this doc, but tanks anyway for your time! And yes, I will prob have to ask about this query because it takes soo long to proceed.

Comment: You're welcome. Well you are selecting **EVERYTHING** from a table so it's bound to take a while if you have a large quantity of data, case in which you may want to consider [lazy-loading of only the necessary to display data](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/datamodel/datamodel-providers.html#datamodel.dataproviders.lazy) instead of loading it all into memory.

Comment: Yep, Im actually considering using addon [Lazy Query Container](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/lazy-query-container).

Answer (score 2):

Use [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) instead of [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

[`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) preserves the insertion order.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have no impact of this type because I'm using  [JdbcTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html). But don't worry, both problems are solved in comments under question :)

Comment: @DawidFieluba If your problem was solved, please post an Answer showing how. You can post and accept your own Answer.