# How to setItems in vaadin grid when items are in a map

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin8, vaadin-grid

I am trying to load use this query and the values into a map

```
LinkedHashMap<SCRegionPriority, String> hash = new LinkedHashMap<>();
pstmt=("SELECT a.Id,a.RegionName,ISNULL(b.Priority,0) as priority 
      FROM dbo.region a left join dbo.SCMap b on a.Id = b.RegionId 
      and a.CountryId = b.CountryId and b.SCId=1 where a.CountryId ='1'")
ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
con.commit();
    while (rs.next()) {
            SCPri c = new SCPri();
            c.setRegionid(rs.getInt(1));
            c.setRegionname(rs.getString(2));
            c.setPriority(rs.getInt(3));
            hash.put(c, String.valueOf(rs.getInt(3)));
        }
```

the query gives me the following values:

> 1,0|2,1|3,1|4,2|...

And then I am trying to load this into the vaadin grid like the following:

```
     List<HashMap<SCPri, String>> rows = new ArrayList<>();
     LinkedHashMap<SCPri, String> fakeBean1 = subdao1.getSCMap(subcontractor.getId(),subcontractor.getCountryId());
     rows.add(fakeBean1);
     Grid<HashMap<SCPri, String>> grid2 = new Grid<>();
     grid2.setItems(rows);

     for (Map.Entry<SCPri, String> entry : s.entrySet()) {
         grid2.addColumn(h -> h.get(entry.getKey().getRegionname())).setCaption(entry.getKey().getRegionname());
     }
     addComponents(grid2);
```

I am not able to load the grid with the columns dynamically generated and one editable row of with values underneath those columns.
I am trying to make the grid look like the following:

```
r1|r2|r3|r4
0 |1 |1 |2
```

I tried to follow the following two links but failed to get it working:

- [How to fill Vaadin Grid with Map items type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45548691/how-to-fill-vaadin-grid-with-map-items-type)
- https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/16038356/grid-8-without-bean-class

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You say that your attempt doesn't work, but you don't mention in what way. Are there compilation errors, and in that case from what part? Are there runtime exceptions, and in that case what are the exception details? Does the wrong thing show up on the screen, and in that case what does it show?

Comment: I am getting only the column names like r1,r2,r3,r4 with one empty row and no values. I dont see any exception or anything as such.

Answer (score 0):

A single row with empty cells implies that the value provider callback for each cell returns `null` (or `""`).

In your case, the value provider callback is `h -> h.get(entry.getKey().getRegionname())`. Here, `h` represents the row object, i.e. your single `HashMap<SCPri, String>` instance. I'm assuming `getRegionname()` returns something like a `String`, which would surely cause `null` results from `h.get()` since `h` uses `SCPri` instances as they key. Changing the callback to `h -> h.get(entry.getKey())` instead might do the trick.

It is an unfortunate leftover from the pre-generics times that `Map::get` accepts any `Object` without compilation errors instead of requiring you to pass an instance of the actual key type of the map.

Comment: Oh yes, `entry.getKey()` worked and i got the values. . I just have one more doubt regarding this. How can I set inline editor for this row as I am getting an error saying I cannot do it this way and need to add the mapping if I try to set using this line `grid.addColumn(h -> h.get(entry.getKey())).setEditable(true).setEditorComponent(tf,h -> h.get(entry.getKey())).setCaption(entry.getKey().getRegionname());` Please suggest

Comment: Second parameter of `setEditorComponent` is a setter, not a getter. You could try something like `(h, value) -> h.put(entry.getKey(), value))`